# How can I set lockscreen notification text from ScheduledTaskAgent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have ScheduledTaskAgent1 that time to time does stuff, and when certain events happens I want to set a notification text. How do i set the lorem text:

[image]

Tried to follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207048(v=vs.105).aspx but Im expecting some kind of function or something.... Anyone?

Comment: no idea but why not do a search from the tool bar on the entire project for that lorum text? pretty sure it must be written somewhere and youll find it eventually with a search XD

Comment: there is no source to download...

Comment: no but you should have your own local copy? unless that image isnt a screen shot of yours but of the demos, when you run your local copy does it have that text? or is it empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article on [setting the lockscreen images and text here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Lock_Screen%3a_Background_image.2C_counter.2C_and_text).

> You can add text and a counter to the lock screen as well, by assigning values to the app's pinned tile.

Comment: +1 om Bryant's answer. Just follow the tutorial above and you should easily set the lock screen from a background agent.

Comment: I'm using an IconicTile and regardless of what I set for Title or WideContent, the Text on the Lockscreen is not shown. The Lock Icon and its count are shown nevertheless. Does it only work with the FlipTile?